# .Net Windows webBrowser - how to extract authorization header from webBrowser response and send to another consecutive request?

Tags: c#-4.0, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control, webclient, system.net.httpwebrequest

I have a windows desktop application. I need to open SSO login page in windows application. For this, I am using **windows web browser control** to open SSO login page. Once successfully logged-in, **I need to get Authorization header from SSO login and use this authorization token for consecutive REST calls**.

The issue here is, **I am not able to extract authorization header Navigated and DocumentCompleted events**. Can anyone suggest how I can extract this authorization header from the first call and how I can use the same header for subsequent REST calls?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hey Ashok same problem here

Comment: Posted my answer for same question @RamaKrishna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this myself.

As I explained in question, for Entitlement login, I'm login to actual website login page. Once I logged in to login page, I receives authorization token from response in DocumentCompleted event. And I am using same token for subsequent REST calls.

Comment: wow excellent! I need same thing to do can you give me the steps to capture authorization token from response in DocumentCompleted event

Comment: Are you using Siemens Entitlement Services or something else?

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: I am using Java REST APIs to authenticate user

Comment: it looks like you are not using WebBrowser .net control to show SSO/Entitlement login page.

Can you please explain complete end to end scenario what you have and what you want?

Comment: I am using WebBrowser .net control only for SSO (One login) login page

Comment: Yes..thats what is expected..and in this control...you need to parse authentication token..   string docu = this.wbEntitlementLogin.DocumentText.ToString();
                    int authIndex = docu.IndexOf("Authorization: \"");
                    int authEndIndex = docu.IndexOf("\"};");
                    if (authIndex != -1 && authEndIndex != -1)
                    {
                        string authToken = docu.Substring(authIndex + 16, ((authEndIndex) - (authIndex + 16)));}

Comment: This all stuff we need to write in DocumentCompleted event right?

Comment: yes..but this is valid if your web site page is returning authorization token in home page after login...make sure this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157549/discussion-between-rama-krishna-and-ashok).